# Grepping exact text only to output?

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

Lets say I have this line of text:

```
#cat numbers.txt
Numbers!!!! John=55 May=43 RandomData Alex=72 Ben=90 End
```

But am only interested in the number John's number. How do I remove all the other stuff that I don't want and turn the output into:

```
#cat numbers.txt | <some command line magic>
John=55
```

Note: I do not know where "John" is located in the text file, or what number is allocated to John.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' numbers 
John=55
```

Provided the information you want always is in the second field.

**Edit:** As per *your* edit, since you don't know where John is located in the file, I would then do:

```
egrep -o 'John=[0-9]{2}' numbers 
John=55
```

Comment: The information I want can be anywhere in the text file.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks man, that was exactly what I need. But if I may ask, what is the {2} for?

Comment: The `{2}` means grep any digit `[0-9]` 2 times. If it needs to support more digits, you will have to adjust the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want whats between between John= and the following space delimiter (could be any number of digits and you don't need to know in advance)

```
grep -Po 'John=\K.*?(?= )' numbers
```